# Small number causes java.lang.ClassCastException when snakeyaml deserialized object is passed to Gatling feeder

Tags: scala, gatling, snakeyaml

I'm running a gatling simulation that uses numeric input from a `yml` file to feed its scenario. Everything works when my numeric inputs are large enough that they cannot be parsed as instances of `java.lang.Integer`, but small numeric values are apparently parsed to Integers and result in a `ClassCastException`.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream
import io.gatling.core.Predef.{Feeder, Simulation}
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor
import io.gatling.core.Predef.{scenario, _}
import scala.collection.JavaConversions

class TestClass extends Simulation {

    val yaml = new Yaml(new Constructor(classOf[Holder]))
    val holder = yaml.load(new FileInputStream("src/test/resources/data.yml")).asInstanceOf[Holder]
    scenario("sim").feed(getUserEmulationFeeder(holder))

    def getUserEmulationFeeder(holder:Holder) : Feeder[Long] = {
        val iterable = JavaConversions.iterableAsScalaIterable(holder.numbers)
        iterable.map(l => Map("userToEmulate" -> l)).iterator
    }

}
```

`data.yml` has the following data:

```
numbers:
  - 30687965369
  - 31415388869
  - 2
```

and is being deserialized into:

```
import scala.beans.BeanProperty

class Holder {
    @BeanProperty var numbers = new java.util.ArrayList[Long]()
}
```

Removing the `2` fixes the `ClassCastException`.

The full stacktrace is:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.runMain(MainWithArgsInFile.java:50)
    at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.main(MainWithArgsInFile.java:33)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToLong(BoxesRunTime.java:105)
    at com.mercurygate.TestClass$$anonfun$getUserEmulationFeeder$1.apply(TestClass.scala:25)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at com.mercurygate.TestClass.getUserEmulationFeeder(TestClass.scala:25)
    at com.mercurygate.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.scala:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.io$gatling$app$Gatling$$$anonfun$1(Gatling.scala:41)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$lambda$1.apply(Gatling.scala:41)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$lambda$1.apply(Gatling.scala:41)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling.run(Gatling.scala:92)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling.runIfNecessary(Gatling.scala:75)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling.start(Gatling.scala:65)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.start(Gatling.scala:57)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromArgs(Gatling.scala:49)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.main(Gatling.scala:43)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling.main(Gatling.scala)
    ... 6 more
```

P.S. Sorry for the complexity of the example. It's only when I combine snakeyaml, gatling, and the small input that I get the error.

Comment: did you have try it `@BeanProperty var numbers = new java.util.ArrayList[java.lang.Long]()`

Comment: Could you prepare minimal small example with all imports? it is really hard to reproduce your issue looking at existing sample.

Comment: @余杰水 's answer is correct. Your problem has nothing to do with Gatling. snakeyaml doesn't know anything about Scala types and `Long` is different from `java.lang.Long`.

Comment: Updated, @AlexeyNovakov. As mentioned, I was not able to reproduce yet with a simpler example. I did not think Gatling was the cause, but simpler examples I tried did not fail.

Comment: That worked, @余杰水.